# PL/SQL Fetching Next and Previous records with EXEC_SQL Oracle forms 6i

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, oracleforms

I am using oracle forms 6i and i am have created a dynamic sql using EXEC_SQL. I am using a single block record however i am unable to navigate between records when i say next_record i am not moving. No errors just the record is not going to the next record;

This code fires every time the user clicks on the *'first','previous','next' and 'last'* buttons on the toolbar. The query is returning the records i am just having problems accessing it thru navigation buttons in a single record block.

**Code**

```
BEGIN   
    cursor_number := Exec_SQL.Open_cursor;  
    recordcount_cursor_number := Exec_SQL.Open_cursor;

  --build SQL
  Sql_Stmt := 'SELECT .......   FROM table WHERE 1 = 1 '||where_clause ||' order by surname';--dynamic where

    --cannot use the dynamic where since this changes based on rowid                                
    Sql_CountStmt := 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ins_reg_no))FROM table WHERE 1 = 1 '||:global.ins_last_where_clause;--dynamic where

--  Show_Message(where_clause);                                                         
    --Parse SQL statement
    EXEC_SQL.PARSE(cursor_number, Sql_Stmt);
    EXEC_SQL.PARSE(recordcount_cursor_number, Sql_CountStmt);

    --Define the cloums for the data to be returned
    EXEC_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(cursor_number,1, ins_reg_no);
    ......
    ......
    ......

    EXEC_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(recordcount_cursor_number,1,totalRecords);

    --Execute the cursor
    Count := EXEC_SQL.EXECUTE(cursor_number);

    CountRec := EXEC_SQL.EXECUTE(recordcount_cursor_number);    

        WHILE EXEC_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(recordcount_cursor_number)> 0 LOOP    
            --SET_ITEM_PROPERTY(CURSOR_STYLE,'BUSY');               
                EXEC_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(recordcount_cursor_number,1,totalRecords);            
                :global.ins_last_record_click := totalRecords;
        END LOOP;

    EXEC_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(recordcount_cursor_number);--very important to close cursor since system can freeze when navigating records

    IF(to_number(:global.ins_last_record_click) != 0)THEN
        :global.ins_last_record_click := totalRecords;

    WHILE EXEC_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(cursor_number)> 0 LOOP


            EXEC_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(cursor_number,1,ins_reg_no);
            .......
            .......
            ........

            --For each operation here that request data to get to the record

                IF(request = 'GET_ALL')THEN
                    --LAST_RECORD;  
                    FIRST_RECORD;       
                    --EXIT WHEN :SYSTEM.LAST_RECORD = 'TRUE';                                           
                ELSIF(request = 'NEXT') THEN
                    --LAST_RECORD;
                    NEXT_RECORD;                
                ELSIF(request = 'PREVIOUS')THEN
                --LAST_RECORD;
                PREVIOUS_RECORD;
                ELSIF(request = 'FIRST')THEN
                    FIRST_RECORD;               
                END IF;

            END LOOP;       


            EXEC_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cursor_number);--very important to close cursor since system can freeze when navigating records   
            --set form fields qual to the cursor data
            :ins_reg_no             := ins_reg_no;
            :ins_mar_stat           := ins_mar_stat;
            :ins_oth_name           := ins_oth_name ;
            :ins_sex                := ins_sex;
            :ins_dob                := ins_dob;
            :ins_pob                := ins_pob;
            ...............
            ...............

      GO_BLOCK('TOOLBAR-BLK');  
    ELSE
        Message('Query Caused No Records To Be Retrived',NO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    END IF;

END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you modify the query data source name property in the block (forms) to your query, in parenthesis i.e. (select... from... where...) and change the query data source type property to "From clause".

You can also change the query text in your code, with the set_block_property built-in package.

It's a lot easier than basing your form in a package.

Check this out: https://sites.google.com/site/craigsoraclestuff/oracle-forms---how-to-s/forms-how-to---base-a-block-on-a-from-clause-query

As for the "single record block" I suggest you try using a multirecod one, but set the number of records displayed property to one.

Hope it helps.